# Highchart : How to plot Stacked bar graph with line by below JSON respons

Tags: html, jquery, highcharts

I am using below Json to plot the stacked graph with line (look like below screenshot)

```
[{
                    "TD": "2",
                    "TE": "5",
                    "TI": "3",
                    "TLI": "2",
                    "TR": "2",
                    "hour": "0",
                    "totalCount": "14"
                },
                {
                    "FINGERVERIFY": "4",
                    "LI": "1",
                    "TD": "3",
                    "TE": "9",
                    "TI": "4",
                    "TLI": "3",
                    "TLIP": "2",
                    "TR": "3",
                    "hour": "1",
                    "totalCount": "29"
                },
                {
                    "LI": "1",
                    "LIP": "1",
                    "LLI": "1",
                    "LLIP": "1",
                    "LR": "1",
                    "LRP": "1",
                    "hour": "2",
                    "totalCount": "6"
                },
                {
                    "FE": "2",
                    "TE": "2",
                    "hour": "8",
                    "totalCount": "4"
                }
            ]
```

[Chart Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUchy.png)

Description of chart based on the below points:-

1. x-axis : "hours" from Json property
2. tip of the line shows the "totalCount"
3. stacked bar shows the other property of Json.

Can anyone please help me to achive above graph which is simlar to screenshot, by using above Json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your data, you need to build a series structure required by Highcharts. Example:

```
const series = [];

data.forEach(dataEl => {
    for (const key in dataEl) {
        if (key === 'hour') continue;

        const existingSeries = series.find(s => s.name === key);

        if (!existingSeries) {
            series.push({
                name: key,
                type: key === 'totalCount' ? 'line' : 'column',
                data: [[Number(dataEl.hour), Number(dataEl[key])]]
            });

        } else {
            existingSeries.data.push([Number(dataEl.hour), Number(dataEl[key])]);
        }
    }
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/40pgqn9j/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series